# Bring equal list elements together

Tags: python, list

Is this an alright way to bring equal elements together (make them appear consecutively in the list)?

```
>>> a = [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8]
>>> for x in reversed(a):
        a.remove(x)
        a.append(x)

>>> a
[8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 7]
```

Edit: List where it allegedly doesn't work (see comments):

```
>>> a = [2, 7, 1, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8]
>>> for x in reversed(a):
        a.remove(x)
        a.append(x)

>>> a
[8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 7]
```

Comment: You should not iterate and modify the list at the same time. Why cant you just sort it?

Comment: @JBernardo Yeah, I agree. But do you know why this even works? I would expect nothing to be changed or having a list that has missing items but not a list with clustered items.

Comment: @JBernardo Bah, that would be less interesting. But yeah, I messed this up. I guess I could've made "in order of last appearance" a requirement, although that just makes the sorting less convenient.

Comment: @Asocia It works because the reverse iterator keeps an index value from last to first and he always keep the list the same size with remove+append. But that could be undefined behavior on a different python implementation

Comment: @Asocia See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why/how it works, and about this possibly being an undefined implementation detail:

The iterator [starts at the end](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/583ee5a5b1971a18ebeb877948ce6264da0cc8aa/Objects/listobject.c#L3302):

```
                             iterator
                                ↓
a = [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8]
x = undefined
```

Then the `for` loop asks the iterator for an item. After getting the last 8, the iterator decreases its index into the list and returns the 8 ([code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/583ee5a5b1971a18ebeb877948ce6264da0cc8aa/Objects/listobject.c#L3340-L3343)), which the `for` loop stores in `x`. So now we have:

```
                             ↓
a = [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8]
x = 8
```

Then `a.remove(x)` removes the **first** 8, which shifts all later items to the left:

```
                             ↓
a = [2, 7, 1, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8]
x = 8
```

And `a.append(x)` appends it at the end:

```
                             ↓
a = [2, 7, 1, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8, 8]
x = 8
```

Then the `for` loop gets the next item from the iterator, which is the same 8 as before, only at the lower index:

```
                          ↓
a = [2, 7, 1, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8, 8]
x = 8 (same one again)
```

The `remove` again removes the **first** 8 (which was originally the *second* 8):

```
                          ↓
a = [2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 8, 2, 8, 8]
```

And it gets appended:

```
                          ↓
a = [2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 8, 2, 8, 8, 8]
```

The next round moves the originally *third* 8 to the end:

```
                       ↓
a = [2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

And then finally the originally *fourth* 8 (which we've been finding over and over again) moves as well:

```
                    ↓
a = [2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

The same then happens to the 2's, 1's and the 7, so we end up with:

```
a = [8, 8, 8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 7]
```

JBernardo commented that it *"could be undefined behavior on a different python implementation"*. I guess it could be, but I'd blame that implementation. The Python reference documentation [notes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) (although about the forward iterator):

> There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the loop (this can only occur for mutable sequences, e.g. lists). An internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and this is incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached the length of the sequence the loop terminates. This means that if the suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the sequence, the next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of the current item which has already been treated). Likewise, if the suite inserts an item in the sequence before the current item, the current item will be treated again the next time through the loop.

And that's *not* marked as a CPython implementation detail, which the Python documentation does at plenty of other places: 261 results for googling [site:docs.python.org/3/ "CPython implementation detail"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.python.org%2F3%2F+%22CPython+implementation+detail%22)

Answer (score 2):

Just use `list.sort`:

```
a = [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8]
a.sort()
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

If u want it in descending order, then pass `reverse = True` to `list.sort`:

```
a = [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8]
a.sort(reverse = True)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, giving no guarantee on the order of the output, but that is O(n) instead O(n*log(n)) for the solution using sort: count the values, and create a new list with the corresponding counts for each value:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8]

counts = Counter(a)
out = []
for value, count in counts.items():
    out.extend([value]*count)
    
print(out)
# [2, 2, 2, 7, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

---

As suggested by @Manuel, there is a `Counter` method that I had never noticed, [Counter.elements()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements):

```
Return an iterator over elements repeating each as many times as its count. Elements are returned in the order first encountered
```

So, to get an output in original order, and in O(n), the code would be simply:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1, 8, 2, 8]

out = list(Counter(a).elements())

print(out)
# [2, 2, 2, 7, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8]
```

Comment: The order is guaranteed on Python 3.6+

Comment: @JBernardo That's right, and in this case, the output will be grouped in the order the values appear in the original list.

Comment: Could also use the `elements()` method.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks, I had never noticed that one! I added it to the answer.